# problem with jquery $.ajax

Tags: jquery

I've search on many websites and i couldn't find why it doesn't work (and in some cases, i do not understand how to fix the problem with other person issues)

So everything works fine in Ie and firefox, but not chrome and opera, i got this error :

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load "*the
>   adress of the file"* Origin null is
>   not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

i got this in my  (the last version of jquery is loaded)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

 $("#translate a").click(function(){    
    page=($(this).attr("href")); 

    $.ajax({

        url: page, 
        cache: false,
        success:function(html){
            afficher(html);     
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrows){
        }
    });
    return false; 
   });

});

function afficher(donnees){ 
    $(".contenu").empty(); 
    $(".contenu").append(donnees); 
}
</script>
```

and this is my html:

```
<div class="contenu"> Lorem ipsum dolo si amet Lorem ipsum dolo si amet Lorem ipsum dolo si amet Lorem ipsum dolo si amet
            </div>


<div id="translate"><a href="fr1.html">FR</a> <a href="en1.html">EN</a></div>
```

Sorry for my english, and thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try with  url: 'http://youdomain/'+page

Comment: @greg Is it being called from your domain or from a local file? AJAX can online get files from the domain the script is from. e.g. If you go to http://thisdomain/ajax.html, AJAX in ajax.html can only download files from http://thisdomain/.